# Vagrant from development to deployment

Tags: deployment, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am using Vagrant Homestead box to be specific to build my app and I would like to move it to the deployment server.

The deployment server is completely empty with only Ubuntu created on it. The problem is that I want to have the same specs and software in the Homestead box (along with same version of software like mysql, redis, apache.. even the structure of the folders.) in the deployment server.

I understand there is a script that each box run in order to set the environment. Should I run the same script in the deployed server?

Comment: Box the vagrant instance in development and then import it on the deployment server. I can be more specific with more details from you, but in general that is the easy and quick answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for your reply. What details are necessary for you to help me further?

Comment: I would probably need access to information about your application stacks and environment, which is kind of outside the scope of SO and more in the scope of what I do for a living. Give my suggestion a try and see what problems you run into.